# Where can I find a wash and fold in Marrakesh, Morocco?

Tags: morocco, marrakech, laundry

I would like to wash about 4kg of laundry in Marrakesh. Finding a place to do this has been tricky. Most places only do dry cleaning or industrial loads. Many tourist forums link to this website: https://lostinmarrakech.jimdo.com/laundry/ however as of September 2017 it says they are closed "due to corruption." My hotel is massively expensive - socks are $3 for the pair.

How do people wash clothes in Morocco? Is there a place I can drop off my clothes to be washed? (Or for them to come pick it up and wash)?

Comment: a google maps search in arabic revealed a few options (laundry), the wash and fold do not exist in middle east and north africa in general, these laundry places are usually cheaper than hotels: https://www.google.com.sa/maps/search/%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A9+%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B3,+%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%83%D8%B4%E2%80%AD%E2%80%AD%E2%80%AD/@31.6365387,-8.0379058,13.15z?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

According to this [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293734-i9196-k4132295-Laundry_done_in_marrakech_or_Fez-Marrakech_Marrakech_Tensift_El_Haouz_Region.html) post, "regular" laundromats are very rare (aka don't exist) in Marrakesh. Residents do laundry in their own home. From how I see it, your options are to ask the hotel to do it, befriend a local to wash it, or just wash them yourself in your hotel room. If it were me, I would wash it myself in this situation.